# Yii2 Select2 dropdown in Kartik Gridview as Cell Value is not working

Tags: gridview, yii2, jquery-select2

I m trying without success to add a Select2 Dropdown in a Kartik Gridview, but it s only appearing in the first element(line) of the Gridview. It s working with a simple dropdown but not with select2 dropdown. I would like to use a Select2 Dropdown instead of a simple Dropdown.

I do like below:

```
echo GridView::widget([
     'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider,
     'columns' => [

        ['class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],

         ... // Some Parameters

         [  
            'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Status'),
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($model) {

            /* ******** Working fine *******/
            /*
             return Html::activeDropDownList( $model, 'jaStatus',  
                   [ 1 =>'Submitted', 2 =>'Processed', 3 =>'Approved', 
                     4 =>'Declined'
                   ],['onchange' => 'updateApplicationStatus()']);
           */

            /* ******** Don't work *******/                  
            return Select2::widget([
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'jaStatus',
                    'data' => [ 1 =>'Submitted', 2 =>'Processed', 
                                3 =>'Approved', 4 =>'Declined'
                               ],
                    'hideSearch' => true,
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                             'allowClear' => false,
                    ],
            ]);
            }
        ],

       [
        'class' => '\kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'header' => 'Actions',
        'template' => '{view}',
        'buttons' => [
                        ...
         ],

        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                                ...
                        }

      ]

    ],

    ... // some settings
]);
```

Am i doing wrong somewhere? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is for Select2 in filter (not as a cell value):

```
[  
    'label' => Yii::t('app', 'Status'),
    'attribute' => 'jaStatus'
    'filterType' => \kartik\grid\GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
    'filter' => [
        1 => 'Submitted', 
        2 => 'Processed', 
        3 => 'Approved', 
        4 => 'Declined'
    ],
],
```

Comment: I think this one is for the filter. What i want to achieve is not the filter, but a select2 Dropdown for each model element "jaStatus".

Comment: Oh, right, sorry. I've misunderstood. I'll leave this in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

please add to Select2 options section and define "id" and "name" attribute. This work very fine.

Example:

```
return Select2::widget([
                    'model' => $model,
                    'attribute' => 'jaStatus',
                    'data' => [ 1 =>'Submitted', 2 =>'Processed', 
                                3 =>'Approved', 4 =>'Declined'
                               ],
                    'hideSearch' => true,
                    'options' => [
                                    'id' => 'jaStatus_'.$model->id,
                                    'name' => 'jaStatus_'.$model->id,
                                 ],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                             'allowClear' => false,
                    ],
            ]);
```